# Unity - Blocking character from walking off ledges

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, controller, angle, raycasting

I don't want my player to be able to walk off ledges. I did this by shooting a single raycast downwards in front of the player, and if ground is NOT hit, then ignore input.

However this is jarring, especially if you diagonally walk along an edge you just completely stop, rather than 'slide' along it.

So I thought I could add two raycasts, one per side to detect which side the ledge is, then allow movement (or steer) the player as applicable.

[image]

The problem is I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I'm using a character controller for movement, my current code is like:

```
velocityXZ = velocity;
velocityXZ.y = 0; // we deal with gravity elsewhere
velocityXZ = inputDir * playerSpeed;

if (facingDropLeft || facingDropRight) {
    velocityXZ.x = 0;
    velocityXZ.z = 0;
    }
velocity = new Vector3(velocityXZ.x, velocity.y, velocityXZ.z);

// handle gravity

charController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
```

Could anyone offer some insights into what direction to look into, or methods I will need?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to accomplish an enjoyable result you should use invisible walls. I think that probuilder can help you.
This is the approach I would have with this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use boxes to make wall than turn off the mesh renderers this will make invisible walls

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use box collider on empty gameObject or simply add a cube adjust the scale accordingly and turn of mesh renderer to make invisible wall